# Find all integer solution of the equations:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integer solutions of the equations:
\begin{cases}
 6x+21y&=&33 \\
14x-49y&=&13
\end{cases}

I'm not sure how to find all integer solutions for a, but I know there are no integer solutions for b, because $\mbox{gcd}(14,49)=7$ and $7$ does not divide $13$.

Comment: In a), first step is to divide through by 3.

Comment: I know that.  Which gives 2x+7y=11.  By looking at it I can tell one integer solution is x=2 and y=1, but I don't know how to find all integer solutions.

Comment: Good. Now, solve for $x$ and figure out what $y$ has to do to make $x$ an integer.

Answer (score 1):

For a, can you find values $a$ and $b$ so that $2(x+a)+7(y+b)=2x+7y$?  If so, then given one solution (which you have) you can get more by $x'=x+na, y'=y+nb$ for any integer $n$.  Then you need to prove that these are all the solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the only values for a, and b that would make 2(x+a)+7(y+b)=2x+7y would be a,b=0.  What does this tell me?

Comment: @PinkPanda:  that is not true.  You can cancel the terms in $x$ and $y$, leaving $2a+7b=0$.  Doesn't that have a solution in the integers?  In fact, many of them?

Comment: Oh, I see.  It does have many, such as a=-7 and b=2.  Still don't see how I would solve for all integer solutions.  Do I solve for a and then solve for b?  a=-7b/2 and b=-2a/7

Comment: @PinkPanda:  so in addition to your solution of $(2,1)$, you can have $(2-7,1+2), (2-15\cdot 7, 1+15\cdot 2), \ldots $

Answer (score 0):

2x+7y=11 => 2x= 11-7y

11-7y must be even. For xy>0 your solution is unique

For xy<0, y must be an odd so that multiplied by 7 will make an odd and finally added with 11, make an even. So y can be every odd number, there will always be a x for that.